# how to truncate the stackLabels on yaxis for a stacked Grouped column highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to truncate long stackLabel name on the yaxis: currently if I do I dont see the labels with long name: it shows like this:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/1pov7nw3/

code:

```
 yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          //offset:10,
          title: {
            text: 'Number of fruits'
          },
          stackLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            //y:160,
            style: {
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: 'gray'
            },
            formatter: function() {
              return this.stack;
            },
          }
        },
```

any idea how to add ellipsis to these labels so that they show up and not collide with other labels next to it in case they are long ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formatter function to truncate name displayed on `stackLabel`. That being said, number of characters to display should change based on **available landscape** and ideally you should recalculate on size change.

Also beware that Highcharts renders `svg` elements and not `HTMLElement` and hence some CSS styles will not be applicable. For example, you can update your `formatter` function to only allow 6 chars:

```
...
formatter: function () {
    let label = this.stack || '';
    let truncatedLabel = label.length <= 6
        ? label
        : `${label.substring(0, 6)}...`;
                  
    return `<span class="myClass">${truncatedLabel}</span>`;
}
...
```

Comment: but how can I show ellipsis- if I do ``` return `""<div class="someClass">"``` +this.stack.substring(0, 6);+ "</div>" and define ```text-overflow: ellipsis``` its does not add any ellipsis

Comment: @user1234 check my updated answer, be aware that highcharts renders `svg` elements and not all style is applicable to svg elements. Take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/09x2nmrk/3/